# How to scroll to right most of WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I need to display an image to read from right to left (Manga). So I want Webview scroll to right most when page is load. I know that scrollTo(int x,int y) may help but i dont know how to indicate the "right most".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact code, but algorithmically, I would think something like scrollTo(webViewWidth - screenWidth + 1, 1) should work. Unless the x and y start at zero, then just remove the +1 and make the y value 0.